# Future<List<Books>> vs Future<List<Future<Books>>>

Tags: flutter, drift

How do we change the function below, so it returns Future<List> instead of Future<List<Future>>

```
Future<List<Future<Books>>> searchBook(String searchString) async {

    return await  appDb.customSelect(
      'SELECT * FROM books',
      readsFrom: {appDb.books},
    ).map(appDb.books.mapFromRow).get();
  }
```

I'm using
drift_sqflite: ^2.0.1
drift: ^2.13.0

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.5/dart-async/Future/wait.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Future.wait`

```dart
Future<List<Books>> getBooks() async {
  final items = await searchBook();
  final result = Future.wait(items);
  return result;
}
```

Or just `

```
Future<List<Books>> getBooks() async => await Future.wait(await searchBook());
```